# How to properly update in a CRUD application

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, crud

I'm working on a CRUD application using webpack as a module bundler and json:server as a simulated backend. All other operations are working perfectly, but the update fills in the fields as undefined. So if a post is as follows...

```
Post 1

content for post 1
```

If I attempt to edit it, it will show up literally as this...

```
Undefined

Undefined
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, but I think it's an issue of scope. I'm either not referencing something properly or I need to rethink a set of curly braces. At least that's what I think.

In my **http.js** file, the put request is within an HTTP class along with all of the others(post, put, delete, get)

```
...
    // Make an HTTP PUT Request
    async put(url, data) {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application.json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        const resData = await response.json();
        return resData;
    }

...
```

The above code is exported to the **app.js** file which handles a submit post function.

```
...
function submitPost() {
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const body = document.querySelector('#body').value;
    const id = document.querySelector('#id').value;

    const data = {
        title,
        body
    }

    // Validate input
    if (title === '' || body === '') {
        ui.showAlert('Please fill in all fields', 'alert alert-danger');
    } else {
        // Check for ID
        if (id === '') {
            // Create Post
            http.post('http://localhost:3000/posts', data)
                .then(data => {
                    ui.showAlert('Post added', 'alert alert-success');
                    ui.clearFields();
                    getPosts();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        } else {
            // Update Post
            http.put(`http://localhost:3000/posts/${ id }`, data)
                .then(data => {
                    ui.showAlert('Post updated', 'alert alert-success');
                    ui.changeFormState('add');
                    getPosts();
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }

    }
}
...
```

The ui functions, which are imported from a ui module, are all working properly as far as I can see. getPosts is working too, but if it's necessary to see that or the HTML file, I'll be happy to provide it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The updated json file shows up like so. The post with the id of 2 once had content like the post after it.

```
...
"posts": [
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Post Three",
      "body": "This is post three."
    },
...
```

Comment: Can you explain what your "no warnings from webpack" comment is intended to convey?

Comment: That was an error. I'm accustomed to building in frameworks like React and Django where I'm notified of such errors and can trace these things back to the source of the problem. In building this application I'm hoping to get away from my dependency on them. The update part of CRUD has been a particular weakness of mine for some time now, and I was hoping someone could at least give me advice on how to track the problem or tell me where I'm going wrong. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you watched the ajax calls from the browser's network trace tool to see exactly what is in the PUT vs a POST or GET?  It would be good to isolate it to the PUT just to be sure

Comment: As per your suggestion I did. I also tried it on postman. Everything is fine on postman, but judging from what I'm seeing on the trace tool there's something wrong with the put request. We're narrowing it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DDupont I was able to find where I went wrong. Very simple careless typo in headers for the HTTP PUT Request.

```
"Content-type": "application.json"
```

I had a period there. This should have been...

```
"Content-type": "application/json"
```

Comment: Right there under our noses the whole time :)

And people wonder why software can take so much time!